# Google Notification Message style in VB.NET Desktop Application

Tags: vb.net, notifications, gmail

I want to implement message notification Gmail style in VB.NET Desktop Application? It will disappear automatically after showing message. But I don't know how to do it. Would you share your thought? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WinForms in .Net 2.0, you can use the [ShowBalloonTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx) method on the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx?ppud=4) class.

Try dragging a NotifyIcon from the Toolbox onto your form.
Then in your code, you can do the following to display a notification down by the system tray.

```
'Requires NotifyIcon1.Visible to be True, and to have an icon set
NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(15000, title, message, ToolTipIcon.Info)
```

However, you should note that in newer operating system, like Windows 7, the timeout I gave (i.e. 15000 milliseconds) has no meaning since the operating system controls that.

Also, unfortunately it requires the Visible property to be set to true,and to have an icon set. So if you don't want your program to show in the system tray, this wouldn't work (although I notice that when I get Gmail notifications via Chrome, Chrome is running in tray, so maybe that's just how it has to be done).

Let me know if that answers your question.